# Filtering database results laravel 4

Tags: php, laravel

I am able to fetch data from my database and place it on an drop down list. Since everything is fetched, there are items that are on repeat. How am I able to filter the results for it not to be redundant on the drop down list?

Comment: Wait, let me look into my crystal ball.

Comment: @hebron Nevermind, I found a magic lamp..

Comment: I love it when that happens!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT` to not get duplicate entries.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `GROUP BY` clause in your SQL select.

PS : you can post your request in your question ;)